# mapbox : fill-color expression depending of a value (not a color value) from the geojson

Tags: maps, expression, mapbox, geojson

how could I set the color of a shape depending of the value of one of its property in the geoJson ?

let's say I have this features collection :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "district_type": "foo"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [...],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "district_type": "bar"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [...],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this array to match colors :

```
    var colors = {
      foo:'#111111',
      bar:'#222222',
    }
```

Now, I want to add a layer where the shapes have the color from my *colors* var, matching the *distric_type* property of the features.

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'districts-fill',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'geo-districts',
  'paint': {
    'fill-color': ..., //which expression here ?
    'fill-opacity': 0.4
  }
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found out... That's so nice !

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'districts-fill',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'geo-districts',
  'paint': {
    'fill-color': [
      'match', ['get', 'district_type'],
      'foo', '#111111',
      'bar', '#222222',
      'white'// otherwise
   ],
   'fill-opacity': 0.4
  },
```